# What is the proper way to go about deleting an item using Express/MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am kinda new to using NodeJS/Express/MongoDB and I am running into an issue when trying to delete an item using the built-in deleteOne Method. When clicking on the trash can icon(fa fa-trash) in my ejs file, I am expecting the item to get deleted but its not actually deleting anything.

Here I have my server-side code using the delete method:

```
app.delete('/deleteBill', (request, response) => {
    db.collection('bills').deleteOne({billName: request.body.billNameS})
    .then(result => {
        console.log(`bill Deleted`)
        response.json('bill Deleted')
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))

})
```

Here is my client side code that basically makes a fetch to the server side route:

```
const deleteText = document.querySelectorAll('.fa-trash')

Array.from(deleteText).forEach((element)=>{
    element.addEventListener('click', deleteBill)
})
async function deleteBill(){
    const bName = this.parentNode.childNodes[1].innerText
    try{
        const response = await fetch('deleteBill', {
            method: 'delete',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
              'billNameS': bName
            })
          })
        const data = await response.json()//this response came from the server
        location.reload()
        console.log(data)
        console.log(`bName is: ${bName} .`)

    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

and here is my ejs code:

```
<!-- Looping through bills -->
          <% for (let i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {%>
            <%
              const billName = info[i].billName
              const capitalizedBillName = billName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + billName.slice(1)
            %>
            <section class="billBox billCard w-50">
              <div>
                <h2>Name of Bill</h2>
                <h3><%= capitalizedBillName %></h3>
              </div>
              
              <div>
                <h2>Amount Due</h2>
                <h3><%= `$` + info[i].billCost %></h3>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h2>Due Date</h2>
                <h3><%= info[i].billDue %></h3>
              </div>
              <div class="modifyBill">
                <span class='fa fa-trash'>
                </div>
              </section>
              
              <% } %>
```

I think it has something to do with the way I am trying to handle things in the client side javascript but I cannot pinpoint exactly what I am doing wrong. It would be nice to have a different set of eyes look at this. I feel like the way I am trying to delete the item is not standard best practice.

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: I can't delete a item when clicking on the delete icon

Comment: There are too many moving parts. Did you try to debug and localise the problem? Does it send a query to your back end to delete the user? is user deleted in the database? do you have any errors in the browser console, or serverside? please show your effort to troubleshoot the problem

Comment: As @AlexBlex mentioned check where the actual problem is. First you can try to run the server side code individually by running the code directly. And then move to the frontend side step by step.